# What is the non-asymptotic counterpart of the mutual information?

Tags: probability, asymptotics, information-theory, mutual-information, communication

The mutual information of a joint probability distribution $p(x,y)$ tells us, if we send $n$-letter messages with each letter drawn from the marginal distribution $p_X(x)$, that we can use roughly $2^{n I(X:Y)}$ sequences to transmit words to the receiver with small maximal probability of error, in the asymptotic limit of $n\to\infty$.

Is there any non-asymptotic counterpart for these statements? In other words, how can we quantify the amount of information that can be sent through a channel (conditional probability distribution) and recovered on the other end, in the regime of finite (and possibly small) $n$?

Comment: How about [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiT9Mif3-v9AhUrEkQIHe2rAh8QFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cae.tntech.edu%2F~rqiu%2Fteaching%2Fece7750%2Freadings%2F2010_channel_%2520coding_non-asymptotic_fundamental_limits.pdf&usg=AOvVaw09yQbfxNUiyWyUiINS2JMz)?

Comment: @mhdadk that is certainly interesting, thanks. Although a bit different than what I had in mind: as far as I can tell it mostly focuses on showing bounds for the transmission rates, rather than providing recipes to work out the transmission rate itself.

Comment: I was actually thinking more along the lines of the "common information" (or "zero-error information") I found discussed in this paper by Wolf: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1405264 (and something similar introduced previously by Shannon himself: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1056798). But I haven't found much discussion about this so was hoping to get a better understanding of the basic idea